# How to get six packs by doing exercise at home?

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, abs, body-building

I'm a lazy person . But I want to build my body up , without going to the gym . Suggest me some good exercise routine to get those six packs ...

Comment: Lazy won't get a six pack. Six pack takes time, work, and strict attention to diet and exercise program. I would migrate this to fitness, but it would be closed fairly quickly for being poor quality and a duplicate. Here are a couple links for you to investigate: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9979/what-exercises-would-make-up-the-minimum-complete-general-fitness-workout/10021#10021 http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12221/bodyweight-strength-training http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/how-to-get-bigger-and-stronger-with-no-gym-or-weights

Comment: Starve yourself to 6% body fat. With no exercise this will make you scrawny and weak, and it's not healthy at all, but you'll have visible abs and that's about the only way you're going to get them if you take the lazy route.

Comment: @JohnP Can we close this question as duplicates of another site or would we have to migrate it? I fear that it might attract some low-quality/insufficient answers as it doesn't really belong to Health.SE but rather Fitness.SE

Answer (score -1):

You to prioritise high tension low rep range over large rep range with lower tension.

The key in building muscle is something called 'Time under tension'.

A good number of reps for hypertrophy (building muscle) is 8-12 whereas for building strength a good range is <6. You want to build muscle, not strength! (understand the difference :))
(A keynote is this: the abdominals are muscle, and need to be trained accordingly - e.g., they need the same kind of attention as any other muscle; tension > volume)
(A second keynote: approiate tension is key, chose a weightrange where you fail after 12 reps.)

You also need to eat a solid diet, and a low (e.g. very low 6-10% BF, the lower you go the morw definition you get)

Lastly, there are no shortcuts - many (especially product advertisers) would have you believe this; this is false!!)

Visit a site like www.t-nation.com and read some articles - you'll have to educate yourself a little to reach your goal.

I believe theese are the keypoints to achieving a six-pack. Next up you'll have to research some exercises yourself. And remember, regular situps will not do much, the key is ToT (time under tension).. :)

Sorry bout the bad grammar also, was written in a rush.

Comment: Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Comment: -1: If you're in a rush, wait until you finished your answer, proof-read it and applied layout to it before submitting. There is no need to be in a hurry. Additionally, you never bothered to re-visit this answer and fix the grammar mistakes.